# Jquery code, how would i do this?

Tags: jquery

Ok, so i have the following jquery code, and an html page that contains some buttons with the numbers 1  - 2 -3 - 4 and a textbox.

when i click on a button it displays that number in the textbox, however when i click again it deletes that number, how do i make it so that its like a phone number, so i could type  1234 
instead of it deleting a number every time.

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#textbox').val(txt);
});
```

Comment: concatinate the text instead of replacing it?

Answer (score 5):

You need

```
$('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val() + txt);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using the [.val( function(index, value) )](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value):

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#textbox').val(function ( _, value) { return value + txt; });
});
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do this!

Answer (score 4):

You need to append the new value on to the existing. Try this:

```
var txt = $(this).val(); // assuming 'this' is the button instance
$('#textbox').val($('#textbox').val() + txt);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('#textbox').val( $('#textbox').val() + txt );
});
```

Comment: `val()` can be used to get the existing content of an element (http://api.jquery.com/val/), as well as to set a value. So, the code inside of the outer `val()` gets the current value, concatenates the next number you just clicked on, and then sets the value of #textbox to be that new concatenated string.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the old value with new value.You have to append the old value.

```
var oldval= $(this).val();
$('#textbox').val( $('#textbox').val() + oldval);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.....

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test">
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="3">
        <input type="button" id="btn2" value="2">
            <input type="button" id="btn3" value="1">
```

JQUERY :

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
       if($('#test').val().indexOf(txt) >= 0)
       {               
           $('#test').val($('#test').val().replace(txt, ''));
       }
       else
       {
           var displayVal = $('#test').val() + txt;
            $('#test').val(displayVal);
       }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
  var currentValue = $('#textbox').val();
  var pressedValue = $(this).val();

  $('#textbox').val(currentValue + pressedValue);   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for better performance, keep the textbox jQuery obj in a variable, and refrain from using jQuery to access the button value (it's really easy without it):

```
var jTextBox = $('#textbox');
...
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(event) {
    jTextBox .val( jTextBox .val() + event.target.value );
    return false;
});
```